# When given the equation: 2g(x)=1/x^5 wouldn't i divide the 2g to the other side rather then multiply?

Tags: functions

When given the equation: **2g(x)=1/x<sup>5</sup> wouldn't i divide the 2 out of 2g(x**) to the other side rather then multiply?

isn't g(x) that same thing at the output y so couldn't i just dive the 2 to the other side and get **1/2x<sup>5</sup>** instead

I logically calculated it like this: **2y=1/x<sup>5</sup>**, then divided the two over and flipped division to multiplication and got **1/2x<sup>5</sup>**.

Comment: Yup that seems good, or you could have used the properties of exponents to multiply by $2^{-1}$ on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$2g(x)=x^{-5}$$ dividing each side by $2$ we obtain
$$g(x)=\frac{x^{-5}}{2}=\frac{1}{2x^5}$$